# Content Editor Web Part not working on all servers in farm

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-editor-web-part

I have a multiserver farm and on one WFE the CEWPs display fine, but on the other servers they show up on all subsites as :

> Web Part Error: One of the properties of the Web Part has an incorrect format. Microsoft SharePoint Foundation cannot deserialize the Web Part. Check the format of the properties and try again.

Also on all servers if I try to add a CEWP I get a popup with the same message as above.

Another possibly connected symptom is on the root site I just get an Error with a Correlation ID. The only thing that seems useful from items with the correlation ID is something about a command cannot be executed, which is

> "c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\users\temp\appdata\local\temp\xxxxx.cmdline"

I can type in a URL to any subsite and the pages will render, but all CEWP are replaced by the error message.

Comment: its look like permission issue, try this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826786, and how many WFE you have?

Comment: I have 3 WFEs. I keep running accross stuff that says to check the perms on the Windows/Temp and Windows/System32/LogFiles folders but they seem to have the appropriote permissions. Permissions are all the same on all WFEs; 1 works and 2 don't.

Comment: did you try to execute the command on the failling serve from command? try to run under farm admin account as well as App Pool account

Comment: by the way you for which service account it is failing?

Comment: the xxx is variable, and when I go the folder where xxx.cmdline is there is nothing there.

Comment: that's weird, try to IIS reset / Clear the config cache. do you know for which service account the permission failing? may be give that service account full writes on the folders...

Answer (score 1):

Problem turned out to be the IPS (Intrustion Protection System) which was blocking the IIS process requests.

The reason there was a working webserver was because it didn't receive the polices until later. When i got to work today it was showing the same symptoms. Once I spoke to the guy that manages the IPS and learned how to access the logs the problem was obvious.